# How to set react state with new props immediately after calling `dispatch` via react-redux connect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux and I'm trying to build a website. I'm using Material-UI components. The `AppSearchBarInput` is an input in the header where users can search for an id (referred to as `appId` in the code). If `appId` is `found` in the database then I want to redirect to another page (`this.props.history.push('/app/appInfo');`). If the input is blank then I display a snackbar (`AppNotFound`) with warning message as well as when the input doesn't exist in the database.

In the `onKeyDown` method I use `connect` to dispatch an action which checks if the id exists in the database (`dispatch` is called from `getAppInfo` using `redux-thunk`). Then I need to immediately get the new Redux state via props in order to decide whether the id was found or not and depending on this I set `snackBarOpen` local state property to true or false.

The problem is that I can't get the updated props within the same method when calling dispatch. I could use `componentDidUpdate` but then I can't update local store from it. Is there some workaround for this situation either using some react lifecycle method or redux trick?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAppInfo } from '../../actions/appActions.js';
import constants from '../../constants.js';

import { AppSearchBarInputStyles } from '../styles/Material-UI/muiStyles.js';
import AppNotFound from './AppNotFound.js';

import * as log from 'loglevel';
log.setLevel("debug")


class AppSearchBarInput extends Component {
  state = {
    appId: '',
    snackBarOpen: false
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ appId: e.target.value });
  }

  onKeyDown = e => {
    const { appId } = this.state;

    if (e.keyCode === constants.ENTER_KEY) {
      if (appId.trim() !== '') {
        this.props.getAppInfo({ appId });
        this.setState({
          appId: ''
        });

        const { found } = this.props.app; // ! problem here !
        if (found) {
          this.props.history.push('/app/appInfo');
        } else {
          this.setState({
            snackBarOpen: true
          });
        }
      } else {
        this.setState({
          snackBarOpen: true
        });
      }
    }
  }

  handleCloseSnackBar = () => {
    this.setState({
      snackBarOpen: false
    });
  }

  render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { appId, snackBarOpen } = this.state;
    const { found } = this.props.app;
    let message = '';
    if (!found) {
      message = appId === '' ? constants.MESSAGES.APP_BLANK() : constants.MESSAGES.APP_NOT_FOUND(appId);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <InputBase
          placeholder="Search…"
          classes={{
            root: classes.inputRoot,
            input: classes.inputInput,
          }}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
          value={this.state.appId} />
        <AppNotFound message={message}
                     open={snackBarOpen && !found}
                     onClose={this.handleCloseSnackBar}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

AppSearchBarInput.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  app: state.app.app
});

const AppSearchBarWithStyles = withStyles(AppSearchBarInputStyles)(AppSearchBarInput);
const AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter = withRouter(AppSearchBarWithStyles);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAppInfo })(AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter);
```

Comment: There's no `dispatch` in the code you posted. Please, update it to clarify where it should be. *I could use componentDidUpdate but then I can't update local store from it* - why?

Comment: Using `componentWillReceiveProps` solved my problem but it's still not the recommended method to use, though.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your code you have no dispatch method. If data was really fetched, then you're not getting updates because `withRouter` actually blocks shouldComponentUpdate. If you want updated state, wrap the `connect` in `withRouter`.

You should also have a mapDispatchToProps function. Like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  makeDispatch: () => dispatch({ getAppInfo })
})
```

So, instead of:

```
const AppSearchBarWithStyles = withStyles(AppSearchBarInputStyles)(AppSearchBarInput);
const AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter = withRouter(AppSearchBarWithStyles);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAppInfo })(AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter);
```

You should have:

```
const AppSearchBarWithStyles = withStyles(AppSearchBarInputStyles)(AppSearchBarInput);
AppSearchBarWithStylesWithConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppSearchBarWithStyles);
export default withRouter(AppSearchBarWithStylesWithConnect);
```

Please see this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

Comment: Although you may have a point regarding `withRouter` this is not the problem I was to referring to. Changing the order of `connect` and `withRouter` didn't make the problem go away. I do have `dispatch` method inside `getAppInfo`. The problem is that the prop update will only be available after the next tick: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/291#issuecomment-185706321

Comment: @hitchhiker if I understand you, you're trying to synchronously get updated state as props within the function that dispatched global state update? Please correct me if I'm wrong. That's indeed an anti-pattern. You really should consider using `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentDidUpdate`. I once made a lil project in the past that helps demonstrate a way to work around this. In the project UI is instantly updated after light calculations  on window resize. Please tell me if it helps you and I'll update my answer. Find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/233yq699yr

Comment: @hitchhiker However, if you need to update store immediately, then you really should consider using another middleware. There's `redux-saga` and `redux-observable`. I can speak highly of `redux-saga` because of the way it handles action dispatch and general function calls. It is also very advantageous for testing because it uses generator functions and an object representation of every function call. If you were using `saga`, then what you want to do would be straightforward with a `yield put` and then a `yield call`

Comment: " if I understand you, you're trying to synchronously get updated state as props within the function that dispatched global state update" - Yes. However `componentWillReceiveProps` is now a legacy method and its use is discouraged. I don't want to use other libraries like the ones you mentioned. I think memoization is a technique that can be used here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the libraries? For react design patterns they are one of the best. I mean, whether a small or large project. Memoization? Hmmnn.. would be interesting to see how that could be applied to your specific situation.